# Adding Google Sign-In To Web App & Retrieve Group Membership From GSuite?

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-workspace

For an internal web app I'm developing in Python/Django I need to retrieve the user's group membership from GSuite and grant/deny the user access to specific webpages depending on what group they have access to.

I've read about how to add a Google Sign-in button, which works as expected: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

However, the user's basic profile doesn't give me the group memberships. I've checked this documentation page (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetbasicprofile) but can't see any reference to group memberships.

Does that therefore mean I need to connect to the GSuite Admin SDK? If so, can I grant a service account read-only permission to retrieve the group memberships?

Reading this (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and the 0Auth 2.0 authorisation scopes (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#admin-directory) seems to suggest I can only grant the service account domain-wide access to administer GSuite Users, which would be a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with Google Support, they suggest to use the Groups API here:
https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/query-memberships#python_1